# Closing of the Drop Down Menu out of the angle Icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a code java script code used for joomla as hover drop down menu, now i would like to change the code to click but when i click on the down-angle it open the menu but when closing i have to click on the same angle otherwise it is not closing the menu, how to change the javascript code to click anywhere in the body of the website to get that closed.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 var ua = navigator.userAgent,
 _device = (ua.match(/iPad/i)||ua.match(/iPhone/i)||ua.match(/iPod/i)) ? "smartphone" : "desktop";
 
 if(_device == "desktop") {
  $(".mod-languages").bind('hover', function() {
   $(this).children(".dropdown-toggle").addClass(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass("open")){
     $(this).removeClass("open");
     return "";
    }
    return "open";
   });
   $(this).children(".dropdown-menu").slideToggle();
  });
 }else{
  $('.mod-languages .dropdown-toggle').bind('touchstart', function(){
   $('.mod-languages .dropdown-menu').toggle();
  });
 }
});
</script>
```

```css
/* =============== LANGUAGE - DROPDOWN MENU =============== */
.mod-languages {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: -5.5px;
    padding: 0 14px;
    position: relative;
}
.mod-languages.open {
    background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0 !important;
}
.mod-languages a.dropdown-toggle {
    color: #4d4d4d;
    display: block;
    line-height: 46px;
}
.mod-languages a.dropdown-toggle.open {
    background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0 !important;
}
.mod-languages ul.dropdown-menu {
    background: #1F4897 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border: medium none;
    border-radius: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
    max-height: 85px;
    min-width: 100%;
    padding: 0 !important;
}
.mod-languages ul.dropdown-menu li {
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
.mod-languages ul.dropdown-menu li a {
    background: #fff;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 4px 15px;
}
.mod-languages ul.dropdown-menu li a img {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 9px;
    margin-top: 4px;
}
.mod-languages ul.dropdown-menu li a:hover {
    background: rgba(81, 99, 175, 0.6) none repeat scroll 0 0;
}
.mod-languages:hover {
    background-color: #fff;
}
.mod-languages:hover a.dropdown-toggle {
    color: #4d4d4d;
}
.fa-lng {
    transform: translate(10px, 0px) !important;
}
```

Comment: Please add dropdown HTML part.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this, or use a different element with the `dropdown-toggle`. (maybe a button)

```
.mod-languages a.dropdown-toggle {
   width: 100%;
   text-align: center;
}
```

or

```
.mod-languages ul.dropdown-menu li.dropdown-toggle {
   /* Enter your css here */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below codes. I hope it works fine.

```
$(document).click(function(e){

   if($(e.target).closest('.dropdown-toggle').length != 0) 
        return false;

   $('.dropdown-toggle').hide();

});
```